# What is the difference between JasperReport formats?

Tags: jasper-reports

I've found four files. Each of them represent JasperReport. There are

```
A.jasper, A.jrprint, A.jrpxml, A.jrxml
```

What is the difference between them? And what are the purpose of each of them?

Answer (score 12):

- **.jrxml** is a human readable XML file that contains the *report template* i.e. report structure and its formatting rules.
- **.jasper** is the *compiled* report template i.e. compiled .jrxml file. You use this file as the template argument in the JasperReports API.
- **.jrprint** is a serialized *JasperPrint object* i.e. an actual report instance i.e. a template that has been filled with data. This file can be deserialized back into a *JasperPrint object*.
- .**jrpxml** is a human readable XML represenatation of a *JasperPrint object* i.e. an XML version of a template that has been filled with data. This file can be unmarshalled back into a *JasperPrint object*.

Comment: Is there any .jrpxml viewer available ?