# can't seem to view my ireport file in java

Tags: java, jasper-reports

My problem is I can't seem to view the ireport file that i created and saved.
here is the java coding:

```
private void btnreportActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    Connection c; 

    try {
        c = DBConnect.DB();
        String report = "C:\\Users\\p.bwalya\\Documents\\Reports\\NPS Report.jrprint ";
        JasperReport JR = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(report);
        JasperPrint JP = JasperFillManager.fillReport(JR,null,c);
        JasperViewer.viewReport(JP);
    } catch(SQLException | JRException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and here is the error message:

> net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException:
>   org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Invalid
>   byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence.
>   at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.loadXML(JRXmlLoader.java:302)
>   at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.loadXML(JRXmlLoader.java:285)
>   at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:274)
>   at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:219)
>   at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:194)
>   at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:185)
>   at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compile(JasperCompileManager.java:288)
>   at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileReport(JasperCompileManager.java:575)
>   at ireport.main(ireport.java:35)

Does anyone know what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Please add the top lines of your ireport file.

Comment: The best way is to pre compile the jrxml and import to source the .jasper file so as to avoid compiling it every time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You compile the **jrxml** file not the `.jasper` file (its already complied) nor the `jrprint` (JasperPrint object, its already filled)

```
String report = "C:\\Users\\p.bwalya\\Documents\\Reports\\NPS Report.jrprint ";
JasperReport JR = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(report);
```

you need to pass the **.jrxml**

es.

```
String report = "C:\\Users\\p.bwalya\\Documents\\Reports\\NPS_Report.jrxml";
JasperReport JR = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(report);
```

If you like to know more about the different jasper report formats..

[what-is-the-difference-between-jasperreport-formats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33643817/what-is-the-difference-between-jasperreport-formats/)

Note:

1. if you already have the `.jasper` file there is no need to compile the `jrxml`, just pass the `.jasper` file to the `fillReport` instead of the `JasperReport` see  @Lefteris Bab comment.
2. in the `fillReport` consider passing an empty `HashMap` instead of `null`.