# Jasper has not updated file in the jboss server 7

Tags: java, jasper-reports, jboss7.x

I have a Java web project in the Jboss 7 in which I use Jasper reports.
I modified the layout of jasper file tested on localhost this all right.
I deploy the server but it still carries the jasper file to the previous layout. Jasper has not updated at all.
Already cleaned the folders in tmp folder, I stopped and started the server, changed the way in which was saved jasper and nothing works.

```
public class UtilRelatorios {

public static void imprimeRelatorio(String relatorioNome,
        HashMap parametros) throws IOException, JRException {
        FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        ServletContext context = (ServletContext) fc.getExternalContext().getContext();
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse();
        JasperPrint jasperPrint = 
                JasperFillManager.fillReport(
                        context.getRealPath("/relatorios/jasper")+ File.separator+relatorioNome+".jasper",
                        parametros);     
        byte[] b = null;

        try {
            b = JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdf(jasperPrint);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
        }    

            if (b != null && b.length > 0) {
                // Envia o relatÃ³rio em formato PDF para o browser
                response.setContentType("application/pdf");
                int codigo = (int) (Math.random()*1000);
                response.setHeader("Content-disposition","inline);filename=relatorio_"+codigo+".pdf");
                response.setContentLength(b.length);
                ServletOutputStream ouputStream = response.getOutputStream();
                ouputStream.write(b, 0, b.length);
                ouputStream.flush();
                ouputStream.close();
            }   
 }
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**.jrxml and .jasper**

You have surely edited your `.jrxml`, but have you complied it with **success** to a new `.jasper` (the complied version)

and is it the `.jasper` file that you have updated?

Note: in your code you are not compiling the `.jrxml` but using directly the complied version `.jasper`, so you need to overwrite this.

[how-do-i-compile-jrxml-to-get-jasper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4456779/how-do-i-compile-jrxml-to-get-jasper/)

[what-is-the-difference-between-jasperreport-formats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33643817/what-is-the-difference-between-jasperreport-formats/)

If this does not work, output the `context.getRealPath("/relatorios/jasper")+ File.separator+relatorioNome+".jasper"` to understand which file you need to replace.

Comment: I compile the .jrxml using iReport and put the .jasper updated on the project.
Now to test compiled using JasperCompileManager localhost and everything worked out, but the server still carries the old .jasper.
I do not know what might be happening because I've done changes before and there was never this problem.

Comment: You are simple not overwriting the correct .jasper file with a new .jasper file ... there is no other reason (check last date modified  ecc.)... If you don't have some other code that overwrites the .jasper file...

Comment: Petter I saved in the project file already compiled .jasper I just substitute it in the folder.
I have tested compiling .jrxml via code with JasperCompileManager and remains the error.
I have also changed the way the .jasper and the error remains.

Comment: This seems very strange, browser that cache the response?

Comment: I figured out my problem components were adjustable to the size of the texts in Jasper layout. Localhost in the texts apereciam normally, but being the first server in the texts were cut. I left the major components that the texts and it worked.