# Why do I get error when running a jasper report in java code?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I'm trying run a report and I'm very sure that the file is there but still getting this message I try changing directory outside the package inside everywhere. I'm using a Mac(ios).

This the error

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: \Users\jeffyarias\NetBeansProjects\LOAN\src\reporte\cliente.jrxml (No such file or directory) BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 10 seconds)
```

.

```
try{
    Class.forName("org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/Loan", "root", null);
    String reportpath="\\Users\\jeffyarias\\NetBeansProjects\\LOAN\\src\\reporte\\cliente.jrxml";
   JasperReport jr= JasperCompileManager.compileReport(reportpath);
   JasperPrint jp= JasperFillManager.fillReport(jr, null, con);
   JasperViewer.viewReport(jp);
   con.close();
}
catch (Exception ex){
    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: The file cliente.jrxml doesn't exist trry to control if the name is correct?

Comment: yes very sure exist and is there

Comment: Try to control the path?

Comment: I did play around with the path slash outside down everything is driving me crazy because don't make sense

Comment: I will try in windows

Comment: Use `getClass().getResource("reporte/cliente.jrxml")` which returns a `URL` or `getClass().getResourceAsStream("reporte/cliente.jrxml")` which returns a `InputStream`. As a general rule of thumb, unless you dynamically generating the report structure at runtime, you should be using the precompiled version instead

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8758403/filenotfoundexception-while-i-am-using-jasper-report/34623796#34623796

Answer (score 0):

You using `Mac(ios)` try to write the path like this:

```
 /Users/jeffyarias/NetBeansProjects/LOAN/src/reporte/cliente.jrxml
```