# Trying to play sound in Java: NullPointerException

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, embedded-resource, javax.sound.sampled

I'm trying to play sound in Java but it doesn't work and I got error message.
Here is my Code

```
public class PlaySoundClip extends JFrame {


public PlaySoundClip() {
  this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  this.setTitle("Test Sound Clip");
  this.setSize(300, 200);
  this.setVisible(true);

  try {

     URL url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("click.wav");
     AudioInputStream audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url);//Line 27
     // Get a sound clip resource.
     Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
     // Open audio clip and load samples from the audio input stream.
     clip.open(audioIn);
     clip.start();
     clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);  // repeat forever
  } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  new PlaySoundClip();//Line 44
 }
}
```

And I get this error message then I'm not here any sound! How to fix this problem?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException   
    at com.sun.media.sound.StandardMidiFileReader.getSequence(StandardMidiFileReader.java:205)   
    at javax.sound.midi.MidiSystem.getSequence(MidiSystem.java:836)   
    at com.sun.media.sound.SoftMidiAudioFileReader.getAudioInputStream(SoftMidiAudioFileReader.java:174)   
    at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(AudioSystem.java:1145)   
    at playsoundclip.PlaySoundClip.<init>(PlaySoundClip.java:27)   
    at playsoundclip.PlaySoundClip.main(PlaySoundClip.java:44)
```

Reference from [Playing Sound](http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/J8c_PlayingSound.html).

Comment: Most probably `url` is `null`.

Comment: 1) Is `PlaySoundClip` in a package? 2) Is `click.wav` located in the same path in the Jar? 3) See [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/418556) & [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/218384/418556)

Comment: `java.lang.NullPointerException` exception came in `StandardMidiFileReader.java` class provide that class code.

Comment: Yes, PlaySoundClip is in a package. I try use full path of the file then it still doesn't work. I'm sure that my file path is correct because I've done this resource path with image before.

Comment: *"Yes, PlaySoundClip is in a package."*  And what is the package, explicitly?  (now is a good time for more information rather than less, since I don't like playing '20 questions').  Your attempt to answer my 2nd question was not very clear.  Describe the structure of the directories containing the class and the Wav file.  And a tip: Add @kocko (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* a person of a new comment.

Comment: Thank you for your advice,sir. My Directory(Ubuntu) of click.wav is /home/paco/NetBeansProjects/PlaySoundClip/click.wav    PlaySoundClip is my project folder in PlaySoundClip it consist of build ,src ,nbproject ,build.xml , manifest.mf. For more information again I try to use full path which I assume that I should work but it was not and I try to move click.wav to any path of the project folder then it still not working. Appriciate all you help @AndrewThompson

Comment: Since you use Netbeans, put `click.wav` inside the `resources` directory.  Then reference it as `..getResource("/click.wav");` (note the leading `/`).

Comment: It's not working,sir. I got the same error.@AndrewThompson

Answer (score 1):

Something is wrong with `click.wav`, it was not found on the classpath, so `url` became `null`, hence the `NullPointerException`.

You should put the `click.wav` on your classpath, so the program will find it. The most straightforward way is putting into the root folder of the `jar` file.

Comment: I use the class path same as my previously project and I tried to use full path and It Strill doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely in your build phase there is a list of "resources" that are copied from source tree to the output compiled classes. Usually it is a string of regular expressions like "*.txt;*.json;*…" In your case you need to add "*.wav" to it or copy file by hand to the compiler output location.

Most IDEs (Eclipse|IteliJ IDEA) and some ant build scripts have provision for resource copying.

Comment: Turns out it is a bit more involving in NetBeans but one can do it, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718201/how-to-add-resources-to-classpath