# error: package org.jdesktop.layout does not exist

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, grouplayout

I would like to compile the [Universal-G-Code-Sender](https://github.com/winder/Universal-G-Code-Sender) *without* using eclipse. I am on OS X 10.9.2 and When I type `ant`, I eventually get the following error:

```
[javac] Compiling 25 source files to /Users/trewq/Downloads/Universal-G-Code-Sender/build/classes
[javac] /Users/trewq/Downloads/Universal-G-Code-Sender/src/com/willwinder/universalgcodesender/MainWindow.java:212: error: package org.jdesktop.layout does not exist
[javac]         org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout commandsPanelLayout = new org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout(commandsPanel);
```

When I checkout the repo, I do see `./lib/swing-layout-1.0.4.jar` in there. I did set the `CLASSPATH` to `:lib/swing-layout-1.0.4.jar:/Users/trewq/Downloads/Universal-G-Code-Sender/lib/swing-layout-1.0.4.jar` but I did not see any change. I would be grateful for any pointers

*UPDATED*:

I would prefer not to change the source code. I believe the problem is that ant is not able to find the library and this is available in `swing-layout-1.0.4.jar`, and when I did `jar -xf swing-layout-1.0.4.jar`, I do see these classes I believe is what ant is complaining about. I found [this site that shows the classes are there](http://www.findjar.com/jar/net.java.dev.swing-layout/jars/swing-layout-1.0.1.jar.html;jsessionid=252692AC0FBE9421C9436A748744ACED). Here is what I see in my lib directory:

```
 org
  └── jdesktop
     └── layout
       ├── GroupLayout.class
       ├── LayoutStyle.class
```

I understand that this project was created using netbeans, but I would like to see if it is possible to edit CLASSPATH (or some other var) in [build.xml](https://github.com/winder/Universal-G-Code-Sender/blob/master/build.xml) - I did try [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1702511/how-to-include-the-lib-folder-in-the-manifest-classpath-in-netbeans) but same error. I *do not* want to install netbeans.

Answer (score 1):

Pointer:  [`GroupLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/GroupLayout.html) was incorporated into the JSE in Java 6.  Change the import to the JSE version of the class.

Comment: Thanks Andrew - I updated the questions after learning more about the problem.